# Is this type of counter table definition valid?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I want to create a table with wide partitions (or, put another way, a table which has no value columns (non primary key columns)) that enables the number of rows in any of its partitions to be efficiently procured. Here is a simple definition of such a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table
(
    partitionKeyCol         timestamp
    clusteringCol           timeuuid
    partitionRowCountCol    counter    static
    PRIMARY KEY             (partitionKeyCol, clusteringCol)
)
```

The problem with this definition, and others structured like it, is that their validity cannot be clearly deduced from the information contained in the docs.

**What the docs do state** (with regards to counters):

- A counter column can neither be specified as part of a table's `PRIMARY KEY`, nor used to create an `INDEX`
- A counter column can only be defined in a *dedicated counter table* (which I take to be a table which solely has counter columns defined as its value columns)

**What the docs do not state** (with regards to counters):

- The ability of a table to have a static counter column defined for it (given the unique write path of counters, I feel that this is worth mentioning)
- The ability of a table, which has zero value columns defined for it (making it a *dedicated counter table*, given my understanding of the term), to also have a static counter column defined for it

Given the information on this subject that is present in (and absent from) the docs, such a definition appears to be valid. However, I'm not sure how that is possible,  given that the updates to `partitionRowCountCol` would require use of a write path different from that used to insert `(partitionKeyCol, clusteringCol)` tuples.

Is this type of counter table definition valid? If so, how are writes to the table carried out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a table with this structure can be defined, but I'm struggling to find a good use case for it. It seems there is no way to actually write to that clustering column.

```
CREATE TABLE test.test_table (
    a timestamp,
    b timeuuid,
    c counter static,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
);

cassandra@cqlsh:test> insert into test_table (a,b,c) VALUES (unixtimestampof(now()), now(), 3);
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="INSERT statements are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead"
cassandra@cqlsh:test> update test_table set c = c + 1 where a=unixtimestampof(now());
cassandra@cqlsh:test> update test_table set c = c + 1 where a=unixtimestampof(now());
cassandra@cqlsh:test> select * from test_table;

 a                        | b    | c
--------------------------+------+---
 2016-03-24 15:04:31+0000 | null | 1
 2016-03-24 15:04:37+0000 | null | 1

(2 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:test> update test_table set c = c + 1 where a=unixtimestampof(now()) and b=now();
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid restrictions on clustering columns since the UPDATE statement modifies only static columns"
cassandra@cqlsh:test> insert into test_table (a,b) VALUES (unixtimestampof(now()), now());
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="INSERT statements are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead"
cassandra@cqlsh:test> update test_table set b = now(), c = c + 1 where a=unixtimestampof(now());
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY part b found in SET part"
```

What is it you're trying to model?

Comment: I am trying to both partition a time series in a day-based manner, and provide way a way to procure the number of entries in a given day without using the `COUNT` aggregate, which I believe performs a row scan and returns the result. The count and the tuples are never retrieved simultaneously, however, so the counter's inclusion in the table was strictly motivated by a desire to avoid creating a table just for it.

Comment: On a slightly related note, I find it odd that a non-viable table can be successfully created. Can this be considered a bug?

Comment: It is odd. I might suggest opening a JIRA ticket with [Cassandra](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA) if you think it's worth buttoning up.